# 2 input fields to upload one image each (React + Firebase)

Tags: reactjs, image, firebase, upload, firebase-storage

question

I have this code here

```
 handleSave(e) {

const itemConexao = {
  nome: this.nome.value,
  descricao: this.descricao.value,
  codigo: this.codigo.value,
  imagem: this.imagem.files[0],
  imagemTabela: this.imagemTabela.files[0]
}

this.setState({ isUploading: true })
const arquivo = itemConexao.imagem
const { name } = arquivo

const ref = storage.ref(name)
ref.put(arquivo)
  .then(imagem => {
    imagem.ref.getDownloadURL()
      .then(downloadURL => {
        const novaConexao = {
          nome: itemConexao.nome,
          descricao: itemConexao.descricao,
          codigo: itemConexao.codigo,
          imagem: downloadURL
        }
        Base.push('conexoes', {
          data: novaConexao,
          //  { nome, descricao, codigo, imagem },
          then: error => {
            if (!error) {
              this.nome.value = ''
              this.descricao.value = ''
              this.codigo.value = ''
              this.imagem.value = ''
              this.imagemTabela.value = ''
            }
          }
        })
        this.setState({ isUploading: false })
      })
  })
e.preventDefault()
```

}

and in my form I have

```
<div>
    <h2> Nova Conexao</h2>
    <input className='uk-input uk-form-width-large' placeholder='Nova conexao' type='text' ref={ref => this.nome = ref} /> <br />
    <input className='uk-input uk-form-width-large' placeholder='descricao' type='text' ref={ref => this.descricao = ref} /> <br />
    <input className='uk-input uk-form-width-large' placeholder='codigo' type='text' ref={ref => this.codigo = ref} /> <br />
    <input className='uk-button uk-button-default' type='file' id='imagem' ref={ref => this.imagem = ref} /> Imagem  <br />
    <input className='uk-button uk-button-default' type='file' id='imagemTabela' ref={ref => this.imagemTabela = ref} /> Imagem Tabela  <br />
    <button className='uk-button uk-button-default' type='button' onClick={this.handleSave}>Salvar conexão</button> <br />
  </div>
```

See that I have 2 input fields, each one for one image... the field "imagem", which should upload an image, works good. But now, how to upload a second image ( imagemTabela) in this same function? Is not multiple images at once, is two images for different purposes. The "imagem" will show in the page and the "imagemTabela" shows up on a modal.

Any 2 cents here?

Cheers =)

Comment: What is Base.push() are you using some kind of wrapper library over firebase or are you using the sdk directly?

Comment: Base.push() is to invoke from Firebase initialization

Answer (score 1):

Make the file upload function its own function that takes a configurable parameter.

Pull the ref.put bit out of `handleSave`, pass a parameter to this new function that specified where the final url reference is to be saved.

You can then run `handleSave1 with a conditional (if x then save to imagemTabela otherwise save to Imagem) or you can refactor`handleSave` to take the parameter and pass it in when you call the function.

Comment: If you want me to actually write this out for you can you please provide a working example is codesandbox that I can refactor.

Comment: I'm trying to do what you said Josh, but no luck at all so far =\

Comment: If you link to a demo in code sandbox or share a github link I can make the changes for you. https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: [done](https://github.com/tofanelli/hidroconreact) ... I'm having some issues with Code Sandbox and only today the guys could fix my problem... thanks very much =)... everything is set there =)